# "Global" dimension for topological spaces // Geometric interpretation for global dimension of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

The global dimension of a ring $R$ is the supremum of the projective dimensions of it's $R$-modules.

$$\dim (R)=\sup \{\dim_\mathrm{proj}(M):M \in R\text{-mod} \}$$

I'd like to have some geometric picture for the meaning of this number.

If $R$ is noetherian we have that "projective", "locally-free", and "flat" are all equivalent. Any module over $R$ can be considered as a sheaf of$\mathcal{O}_S$-modules where $S=\operatorname{Spec} R$.

A projective resolution of a module $M$ could be thought of as fitting $M$ into the end of an exact complex of vector bundles (locally-free sheaves) over $S$.

This suggests the following story for arbitrary (paracompact hausdorff) topological spaces.

> **Definition 1:** An $(r,k)$-**resolution**  for a vector bundle morphism $f: E_0 \to F_0$ is an exact complex of vector bundles:
>
> $$0 \to E_r \to \cdots \to E_{2} \to E_{1} \to E_0 \to F_0 \to F_1 \to F_2 \to \cdots \to F_k \to 0$$
>
> **Definition 2:** The **left dimension** a morphism $f: E_0 \to F_0$ is the infimum over all lengths of resolutions:
>
> $$\dim_{\leftarrow} (f) = \inf \{n : f \text{ has an $(n,k)$-reolution for some $k\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$} \}$$
>   Dualizing we get the **right dimension** $\dim_\rightarrow(-)$.

Mimicking we get "homological dimensions" for $X$ by taking the supremum:

> **Definition 3:** The **left "global" dimension** of a space $X$ (or a smooth manifold when taking the morphisms in the suitable category) is given by:
>   $$\dim_{\leftarrow}(X) =  \sup \{\dim_{\leftarrow} (f) : f \in \mathsf{Mor}(\operatorname{Vect}(X))\}$$
>   Dualizing we get the **right "global" dimension** $\dim_\rightarrow(X)$.

---

> **(1)** Is the **"global" dimension** in definition (3) a **known/useful concept?** (If not for topological spaces maybe for smooth manifolds?)
>
> **(2)** What are some (more direct perhaps) **geometric interpretations for the global dimension** of a ring?

Comment: There's an existing definition of homological dimension for spaces, and it doesn't look like this: instead you take the largest $n$ such that $H_n(X, L) \neq 0$, where $L$ is any local system on $X$. This recovers the usual dimension for closed manifolds.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah, Interesting. Do you know any place where definition (3) or something similar is discussed?

Comment: No. I don't know any setting where people consider chain complexes of vector bundles on a topological space. It doesn't appear to be a natural level of generality.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, I changed the terminology a bit so it won't be confusing.